# Bundler 2 won't run rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bundler, rspec-rails

We recently updated bundler to 2.0.1 in our project. After the update the app runs fine but I can't run rspec. It does run on my co-workers computer which should be pretty identical setup to mine's.

What I tried:

- `bundler update --bundler` => completes successfully
- `gem update bundler` => completes successfully
- `bundle exec bin/rspec` => Error: `You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.`

  - `bin/rspec` => Error: `You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.`
- `bundle -v` => Bundler version 2.0.1
- `bundle exec bundler -v` => Bundler version 2.0.1
- `bundle exec rake app:update:bin` => completes successfully

Some versions:

- rspec 3.7.0
- ruby 2.4.1p111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was with my default version of bundler. You can see that with `gem list bundler`.

I ended up uninstalling ruby and re-installing it, followed by a fresh installation of bundler 2 and all the other gems. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try remove Gemfile.lock and run `bundle install`, after that try again running the command: `bundle exec rspec`